# glReadPixels returns incorrect image for iPhone 6, but works ok for iPad and iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, glreadpixels, eaglview

I'm using following code for reading on image from OpenGL ES scene:

```
- (UIImage *)drawableToCGImage
{
CGRect myRect = self.bounds;
NSInteger myDataLength = myRect.size.width * myRect.size.height * 4;

glFinish();
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

int width = myRect.size.width;
int height = myRect.size.height;

GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer2);
for(int y1 = 0; y1 < height; y1++) {
    for(int x1 = 0; x1 < width * 4; x1++) {
        buffer[(height - 1 - y1) * width * 4 + x1] = buffer2[y1 * 4 * width + x1];
    }
}

free(buffer2);

CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, myDataLength, NULL);
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * myRect.size.width;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(myRect.size.width, myRect.size.height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

CGImageRelease(imageRef);

return image;
}
```

It works perfectly for iPad and old iPhone versions, but I noticed that on iPhone 6 (both device and simulators) it looks like monochrome glitches.
What could it be?

Also, here is my code for CAEAGLLayer properties:

```
eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @YES, kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
                                kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];
```

Could somebody shed the light on this crazy magic, please?

Comment: Are you using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` to preview your image? I've found that can have weird effects when saving an image generated from a bitmap context without first being converted a png or jpeg format. Try using `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` before outputting your image. Also you should probably specify `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` for the bitmap info.

Comment: @originaluser2 I'm using debugger for previewing images (Quick Look feature). I've just tried to save it as PNG, but result is the same. kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast also didn't do the thing.

Comment: Showing the result might be helpful in finding what is going on..

Comment: @MaticOblak I can't upload an image, but here is a link – https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53403968/glitched.png

Comment: Interesting result. Pinpointing the issue might help. You have 3 parts that may causing this. First is the pixel data you receive are incorrect which may be easiest to test if you create a new texture from the data you get from reading the pixels and then check the frame snapshot to see the texture if it is correct. Second is row swapping which can be checked by using the buffer2 when generating the image. If none of these are causing the issue then the image generating must be the cause. Maybe try kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaLast at least this is what I am using...

Comment: Simply to analyze the image you can see the red, green and blue and black stripes which give a hint that there is an offset by 1 for color components. If bottom part of the image is indeed black and an offset by 1 is made then the colors receiving are (0,0,0,255) for black but you are using them as RGB so the black is (0,0,0) then next line is red as (1,0,0), green (0,1,0)... Or if you put them together (0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1...) If you see what I mean..

Comment: Actually I would expect the issue to be here: CGImageCreate(myRect.size.width Try using integer values. So first get the width and height as integers from bounds and only use those in further computing, not the frame

Comment: @MaticOblak thank you very much! I didn't think about checking the buffer, it was filled incorrectly. Now I've found the issue and will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MaticOblak, I've figured out the problem.

Buffer was filled incorrectly, because float values of rect size were not correctly rounded (yeah, only for iPhone 6 dimension). Instead integer values should be used.

UPD: my issue was fixed with the following code:

```
GLint viewport[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

int width = viewport[2];
int height = viewport[3];
```

Comment: Please add the fixed line(s)